# In which case audioSession.currentRoute.outputs empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a mobile application. It has some play audio. It works fine my devices always, but I receive many crashes from real users in Crashlytic. Simply, my code is:

```
- (void) checkAndResetAudioSession {
.
.
AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
.
.
AVAudioSessionPortDescription * outputPort = [audioSession.currentRoute.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
.
}
```

I get crashes which says:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x106eb3ea0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x106085a40 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x106dc5a90 -[__NSCFArray count]
3  MyApp                          0x303b235e4 -[AudioSessionManager checkAndResetAudioSession] (AudioSessionManager.mm:100)
.
.
```

As I understand, it crashes because of it tries to reach 0th index object of `audioSession.currentRoute.outputs` variable. That means, output should be empty. **In which case, audioSession.currentRoute.outputs can be empty?** As I understand, it is output devices. So, at least there should be always one output device.

Additional information, as I see, this problem happens almost always in iOS 12 and mostly iPhone X, 7 and 7 plus (%50 crashes come from these 3 devices).

Comment: Did you check what happens when you have a bluetooth speaker connected and you move the phone out of range?

Comment: thanks a lot @GerdK , I tried. I dont have airpods, but I have a bluetooth headphone, logitech. when I connect it to the device, it works fine and output has 1 element which is logitech headphone. when I move headphone out of range, than its pairing is disconnected and I still see output has one element but now, it is Speaker. I will try to test with AirPods if I have

Comment: happens also to me, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out why the Outputs of currentRoute can become empty and how to avoid it?